# WIX install .net framework 4 offline

Tags: .net, wix, installation, offline, bootstrapper

I need to install .net framework 4 before installing my app.
I use Wix 3.8.
In bootstrapper i use this

```
<Chain>
    <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx40Redist"/>
    <MsiPackage Id="MyApplication" SourceFile="$(var.MyApplicationSetup.TargetPath)"/>
</Chain>
```

But, this don't install .net Framework without loading it from internet.
I need to install it offline.
I can include in chain ExePackage, and it starts install framework offline, but it starts as isolated application(if i click cancel in install window, installation of framework will continue).
So how, i can install framework using wix offline?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the silent installer command:

```
<PackageGroup Id="Netfx4Full">
    <ExePackage Id="Netfx4Full" Cache="no" Compressed="yes" PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes" 
                InstallCommand="/q" SourceFile="dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe" DetectCondition="Netfx4FullVersion"/>
</PackageGroup>
```

The .net Framework gets installed without opening any window.